# How to store and authenticate on a React app which uses Google Oauth (passportjs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, passport.js

So I am building a sample Reactjs app where I am using Google OAuth for authetication. The Oauth is taken care by a node application using passport.js

The react app is running on `localhost:3000` while the node app is running on `localhost:5000`. I have setup some proxy using `createproxymiddleware` to communicate between them.

In the React app , on the `/` route I have a login screen. When the user clicks on on the Login button , the user is redirected to `/auth/google`. The proxy kicks in and it gets redirected to `localhost:5000/auth/google` where the oAuth flow starts and the user can log in.

Passport.js takes care of the flow and then the user is redirected to `/home/dashboard` which is basically `localhost:3000/home/dashboard`.

The above flow is working fine. But the problem I face is that I want to keep track on the React side whether the user is logged in or not. If he is logged in and visits `localhost:3000/` he must be redirected to `localhost:3000/home/dashboard` else if he is not logged in and tries to visit `localhost:3000/home/dashboard` he must be redirected to `localhost:3000`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I hope you would have added the authenticate middle ware on the server side for the API Requests. Once the user goes to dashbaord, you can try to make a API call to get the basic logged in data or all the meta data that you require to setup the UI. This call if successful assumes that you are logged in. If not the API call would return 401, based on which you can redirect to login screen. Also on the React side, you need to monitor all request and response for 401 and redirect the user to login

Comment: When the user is authenticated, return a value to your redux state and you can create private routes that way.  If you just google "react router private" you should find what you need.